# Spawning monsters at random locations

Tags: c++, loops, vector

```
std::string monsterNames[2] {"Weezer", "Leppin"};

for (int vecID = 1; vecID < 5; ++vecID)
{
    if(newmonster.monsterData[vecID-1].posX != newmonster.monsterData[vecID].posX && newmonster.monsterData[vecID-1].posY != newmonster.monsterData[vecID].posY)
    {
        int randIndex = rand()% 2;
        int randPosX = rand()% 3;
        int randPosY = rand()% 3;

        newmonster.CreateMonster(monsterNames[randIndex], randPosX, randPosY);
        newmonster.monsterData.push_back(newmonster);
    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Yes, this code does not run because of the if statement. No monsters are created until after the statement, therefore array index is out of bounds.
Basically, the program randomises the monster names and coordinates and all works well without the if statement. But I need to check whether a monster already exists at that location and if it doesn't, re-run the loop.. How to do this in a more sensible way? xD
If I don't have the for loop, the random numbers will always be the same.

Comment: You should really seperate the creation of "monsters" from checking if another one exists at the same position (e.g.: have a function that checks each element of the vector if it contains one with the same `posX` and `posY`values)

Comment: Also the else is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I will propose the next solution, you can extract the if statement code into a new function "generateRandomMonster", so you can call it once before the for bucle and reduce the iterations in one, in this way you can ensure that the newmonster array already have one monster and the if statement doesn't break your code.

I hope this solution helps you.

Br.

Comment: I've tried different ways even using a do-while loop.. There's no way around.

Answer (score 0):

Your check is wrong. If it happens that last two monsters are in the same location then stop making monsters. Surely that's not what you want.

In your place I would run a while loop until `newmonster.monsterData.size() == 5`. In loop I would make random coordinates and add the monster only if **none** of the already created monsters share the location. For that check you need an inner loop.